# How to connect domain to WordPress on Google Compute Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I already own a domain from BigRock.in
And I've deployed WordPress on Google Compute Engine (GCE)

I want to connect this domain to my WordPress installation. How do I do that?

And also if it's possible to connect domain to my WordPress installation, how to create subdomains on GCE?

Answer (score 0):

Domains and subdomains are controlled via DNS. You need to make the DNS record for bigrock.in, www.bigrock.in or whatever other subdomain you want point to you GCE instance's IP address.

If you want different subdomains to show different sites you will need to set up virtualhosts in your HTTP server (or perhaps use a Wordpress plugin).